# How to search by list of keywords using asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Im trying make my search method work by list of search keywords.
Is there a way how can I make `await asyncio` work though list `search`?

```
async def _request(query: dict):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        r = await client.post('https://nmmgzjq6qi-2.algolianet.com/1/indexes/public_prod_inventory_track_index/query?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(4.12.0)%3B%20Browser', headers=headers, json=query)
        return r.json()
```

```
async def to_search(query: str, tags: list[str] = [], page=0, hitsPerPage=100):

    data = {
        "query": query,
        "page": page,
        "hitsPerPage": hitsPerPage,
        "facets": [
            "*"
        ],
        "analytics": True,
        "clickAnalytics": True,
        "tagFilters": [],
        "facetFilters": [
            make_tags_filter(tags)
        ],
        "maxValuesPerFacet": hitsPerPage,
        "enableABTest": False,
        "userToken": userToken,
        "filters": "",
        "ruleContexts": []
    }
    return await _request(data)
```

```
import asyncio

search = ['coffee', 'banana', 'apple']
#search = input()

for x in search:
    r = await asyncio.gather(*[to_search(x, page=i) for i in range(10)])
```

Also. Is there a way how to make `search = input()` inputing list of keywords (assuming split them with comas)

Comment: What is `to_search`? Why do you think `asyncio` is appropriate here? If there's no blocking I/O (and you've shown none) that you can convert to asynchronous I/O, `asyncio` won't do anything for you. If you don't know how to split a string by commas, you're *definitely* not ready to start writing `asyncio` code.

Comment: Everything inside ```r```is fully functioning code. Anyway thanks for letting me know. I just update code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make serveral requests with any parameters the way in the code snippet below. Pay attention that it is the easiest way to do it. If you have many tasks, you have to implement producer-consumers pattern using `asyncio.Queue`.

```py
import asyncio
from typing import List

import httpx


async def to_search(url, client: httpx.AsyncClient):
    res = await client.get(url)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return res.status_code


async def main_wrapper(urls: List[str]):
    # you need only one AsyncClient for asyncio app.
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        results = await asyncio.gather(*[to_search(i, client) for i in urls])

    print(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ["http://google.com"] * 20
    asyncio.run(main_wrapper(urls=urls))
```